# sql query to select when dates are greater than x givin parse error < unexpecter

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get the results from  a php script and this returns a white page in a browser. 
So I use php in commande line to see which error are thrown back at me and I get a parse error as below:

```
syntax error, unexpected '>' in file at line 42
```

The line 42 being the line under the WHERE statement but I replaced teh <= by between but still send me exactly the same parse error about this < whereas it is not there anymore. 
This the script being use where there seem to be an issue.

```
$this_sql = "(SELECT
    *
FROM
    " . $db_table . "
WHERE
    field_date BETWEEN '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_date)) . "' AND '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end_date + 60) . "')";
```

I am trying to understand why the '>' is throwing a parse error whereas it is valid SQL and except mistakes my brackets are closing each other fine. I hope this will make sense.

Comment: what does `where field_date >= someDate and someOtherDate` mean?  nothing in any sql syntax i'm famlliar with?

Comment: Can't get your question but instead you need to use `between` within your sql query

Comment: because of the brackets you are getting the parse error

Comment: maybe something like this ? field_date >=  date'" .('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_date)) . "' AND  date'" .('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end_date + 60) . "')";

Comment: write the value of `$this_sql` and test that again in sql.

Comment: @Kritner I am trying to get all results where field_date is  between higher or equal to the $start_date and $end_date+60. The issue I had was replaceing >= by between was keeptin throwing the same error at me with unexpected > whereas this is not in the code anymore so i thought I would provide something which can be investigated

Comment: @Uchiha I replaced <= by between and reloaded the script but it throws me the exact same error with < whereas it is not there anymore

Comment: Can you update your post where you where getting this errror

Comment: @Shane_Yo the $this_sql bring me the results expected with between or <= so I m puzzled about why the PHP fails to get them

Comment: here -> date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_date)) you have two ) and that's wrong

Comment: @Goikiu that was it. like the most tiny things can create the biggest mess. thanks. if you make it an answer I ll validate it

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets creating the string `$this_sql` is breaking the query on execution
(to many closing brackets thus causing the `parse`,`syntax` error):

**Try** :

```
$this_sql = "(SELECT * FROM " . $db_table . 
            "WHERE field_date BETWEEN '" . 
            date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_date) . 
            "' AND '" . 
            date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end_date + 60) ."')";
```

you should be able to post the value from `$this_sql` back into sql for testing.
Should give your a string something like

**Result**

> (SELECT * FROM 
>   yourtable 
>   WHERE field_date 
>  
>   BETWEEN '2015-06-01 12:00:00' AND '2015-09-01 12:00:00')